# get local scope within a method in ruby, a la PERL'S my

Tags: ruby, scope

I am converting from PERL to Ruby.
One of the things I like in PERL is the ability to have local scope within a sub, by using my command.
I.E. This code won't work, because $only_in_the_if is out of scope.

```
...
if (cond) {
my ($only_in_the_if) = bar($foo );
}
bar1($only_in_the_if) ; #can't work, $only_in_the_if scope is finished
...
```

In Ruby, only_in_the_if will be present within the method scope. 
Any ideas?

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve with this code? It might be there's another way to do it in ruby...

Comment: It could be many things. Of course that there are other ways of achieving it, and using a subroutine is the obvious one (although one does need to pass arguments). The idea is that I can "play" with the scope and can garbage collect within the method, and making sure that if someone alters the code, there is very little namespace pollution. I am handling huge files, and this may come in handy.

Comment: Your question is not clear, that is why i'm asking for more information. Are you saying "Will the above code work in the way I'm saying?" ? in which case - why not run it in irb and see?

Comment: I am sorry. It's a coding style question. I know that the code will work in ruby, as I have done this. The scope of the if block is the same as of the method. It is not necessarily so in PERL, hence the "my" command. I was wondering if there is an equivlent to that. Having multiple scope for arbitrary number of variables in the method body. If not, and I may need to have variables only in the scope of the if (temporary very large arrays), I'll create a new method for the if.

Comment: It's ok that it's a coding style question, I've answered them before... I'm just not clear on what exactly you're asking and whether you've already given it a go to see if it does what you want...

Comment: ruby does indeed do scoping...

Comment: I am not sure how much I can say about what I do. It's basically reading huge files, looking for a faulty line in several sections, and then adding lines ith fixes in the correct locations.
As for scoping, are we talking about Within a method body, for arbirtary number of vars? How? All I know is the scoping for the loop variable. I know that Ruby does scoping. And does it with much more ease than PERL, for most cases. Not just this one, as far as I know (hence the question). Thanks.

Comment: ok... I googled the "my" command which is where this was confusing me. Your phrasing above doesn't make it clear that "there is a command in perl called "my" which does this scoping thing..." Given I'm not a PERL programmer - that threw me completely ;) Now I'm clearer on what you're asking, I can't think of something off the top of my head that will do what you're asking... but I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

simple scope clearly doesn't remain within a conditional...

```
irb(main):001:0> if my_cond
irb(main):002:1>   my_var = 'blah'
irb(main):003:1>   puts my_var
irb(main):004:1> end
blah
=> nil
irb(main):005:0> puts my_var
blah
=> nil
```

but you can use a block to force scoping... even though it's a little weird.

```
irb(main):006:0> 1.times { new_var = 'blah'; puts new_var } if my_cond
blah
=> 1
irb(main):007:0> new_var
NameError: undefined local variable or method `new_var' for main:Object
    from (irb):7
    from :0
```

You can probably meta-program that into a method called "my" if you like ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's code blocks are different to Perl's and AFAIK there is no simple way to declaratively scope variables to be lexically only inside compound statements such as if.

You can use a code block as suggested by Taryn. I am not sure the benefit would outweigh the cost (in terms of speed of execution and difference to how other Ruby developers work).

Another simple solution is to keep compound statements lightweight, and rely on shorter methods to achieve tight variable scoping. Where in Perl you might write a 30-line method that has little sub-blocks of 4 or 5 lines inside ifs and fors, instead in Ruby the same flow and scoping could be done with a controlling method that has the main flow, and several private methods where the variables are scoped. Data shared between those methods can be object state (in @ variables) or scoped variables in the controlling method that are passed in as params to the private methods.

```
def main_method foo
  if (cond)
    bar foo
  end
end

private 
def bar param
 only_in_bar = Math.whatever(param)
 # Do some stuff with only_in_bar
end
```

Comment: Yes, that's kinda what I have thought. The local scoping is good a multi-threading pragma we use. It enables scoping out temporary variables, and uses them to minimze chances of deadlocks(lock gone when scope is gone). Yeah, the best thing to do is think in Ruby when writing in it (same for all languages, I guess)